# Alignment multiple DotNet.HighCharts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, highcharts

It seems that the Render method is not supported in DotNet.HighCharts which makes it hard to align multiple charts in the same page. 
I am able to populate multiple charts on the same page, but I am not able to align them next to each other. However they will be displayed after each other. Does anyone has an idea how to display 2 charts next to each other? or even 4 charts as a block?

Note: I am using ASP.Net Mvc3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create a sets of DIVs that will hold one chart DIV container each.
With a layout you decide (side by side or whatever). And then send each chart to the "master" container you want?

Here is some psuedo-code since I am not too familiar with MVC.

Create a table or some other structured container with addressable elements in your display page (aspx, etc). Then add your literal tag for each chart separately inside one of these elements (ie, a table cell). In the codebehind create your individual charts instead of what series of charts.
So something like:

```
<table>
<cell1>
<asp:literal id="ltrchart1">
</cell1>
<cell2>
<asp:literal id="ltrchart2">
</cell2>
<cell3>
<asp:literal id="ltrchart3">
</cell3>
<cell4>
<asp:literal id="ltrchart4">
</cell4>
</table>
```

Then in your codebehind do something like:

```
chart1 as new highcharts("chart1").....
ltrchart1.Text = chart1.ToHtmlString()

chart2 as new highcharts("chart2").....
ltrchart2.Text = chart2.ToHtmlString()

chart3 as new highcharts("chart3").....
ltrchart3.Text = chart3.ToHtmlString()

chart4 as new highcharts("chart4").....
ltrchart4.Text = chart4.ToHtmlString()
```

This is not pretty but it gets the job done.

Comment: @Strider I am not sure then. Maybe after load you can manipulate the rendered DIV containers?

Comment: In order to have multiple charts, am using an action that returns a container of charts:
return View(new DotNet.Highcharts.Container(new[] { chart1, chart2, chart3, chart4 })); 
Then am creating the following view:
@model DotNet.Highcharts.Container
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Multiple charts in one page";
    Layout = "";
}
@(Model)

Later, on the page that is calling the action, am using ajax to display the results in a div. Charts are rendered and displayed after each other. 

What should i change in my code in order to implement the approach your suggesting? 
Thanks indeed.

Comment: Thanks! i followed the same idea. I implemented some Div(s) with the layout i need. Then rendered a chart to each div. No need for a container of charts to be rendered to the same div.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of what [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/TRLmv/)

if you just maximize the result panel you will see them next to each other

Comment: Yes, this would work fine if using straight JS. Note that in DotNet.Highcharts there is no (to my knowledge) method to directly change the DIV container attributes other than the ID.